# Theory: Is the given language context free or not?

Tags: grammar, theory, context-free-grammar

In a recent test , I was asked to recognize if the below language is context free:

[image]

According to me, it is context free, and can be accepted by the below context free grammar, where S is the start symbol and Y is a non-terminal:

[image]

However, my answer was considered to be wrong and so apparently this language is not context free.

I'm confident about my answer, but the response has got me confused. Is my understanding correct? Please let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: Your grammar generates 0100 which is not part of the language

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory; use one of the cs/cstheory stackexchange sites (read their own help to decide which one).

Comment: @MarianV Thanks. Understood the problem now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is NOT context free language! your grammar is wrong!

According to language description `0`s at suffix should be less then number of `1`s and prefix   `0`s. But using your grammar you can generate wrong string as follows:

Step1: Always replace `S` by `S0`
Step2: Now replace `S` to `Y`

```
S --> S0 --> S00 --> S000 --> Y000
```

Now you can replace `Y` to `^`  (nul) it gives `000`, this string is not in your language.

either replace `Y` to `0Y1` then `Y` to `^`:

```
  Y000 --->  0Y1000  ---> 01000
```

`01000` string is not in language. So your grammar does not generate the same language.